# Objective-C: What does this code mean?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

In the MyViewController.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy, nullable, class) void (^saveMetadataSuccess)(MyViewController*const _Nullable myViewController);
```

In the MyViewController.m file:

```
void (^saveMetadataSuccess)(MyViewControllerr* const myViewController) = nil;

+ (void)setSaveMetadataSuccess:(void (^)(MyViewController* const))newMetadataSaveSuccess {
    saveMetadataSuccess = [newMetadataSaveSuccess copy];
}

+ (void (^)(MyViewController* const))saveMetadataSuccess {
    return saveMetadataSuccess;
}
```

And finally the method which I don't understand:

```
- (void)success {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        MyViewController.saveMetadataSuccess(self);
    });
}
```

From my understanding, `saveMetadataSuccess` is a getter, but `MyViewController.saveMetadataSuccess(self);`seems to set something.

Can somebody enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: Getter returns block and block get performed. It's a such weird way to use dot-notation instead of using `[]` and delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyViewController.saveMetadataSuccess` is a getter and it returns a block that then being called with a param (self).

So it's like a function that returns other function.

Also you must not just call `MyViewController.saveMetadataSuccess(self);` because `MyViewController.saveMetadataSuccess` is nullable and it will crash if `MyViewController.saveMetadataSuccess` is null.

You have to check `MyViewController.saveMetadataSuccess` first:

```
- (void)success {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (MyViewController.saveMetadataSuccess) {
            MyViewController.saveMetadataSuccess(self);
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Noting that separating the fetch and the call into 2 statements might have made the intent clearer.  E.g.: `void (^successBlock)(MyViewController *const) = MyViewController.saveMetadataSuccess;
  successBlock(self);`